# rails Using simple form I would like to enable by textbox through a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am currently trying to keep a checkbox in form which enables the text field up it is checked So how can I do it. I am using simple form.

this is simple form

```
  <%= f.input :satisfaction  %>
```

I have tried keeping as below

```
<%= f.input :satisfaction, as: :boolean %>
```

But is only displaying checkbox not a text field.

So can any one tell me how to this.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is invalid. You've missed a comma between the two arguments. Try:

```
<%= f.input :satisfaction, as: :boolean %>
```

Comment: Sorry I have tried like that but I only checkbox but I need both text box and checkbox. and text box should be enabled when checkbox is checked as shown in this example http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/enable-disable.php